# How to give a name to docker image?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, docker

I use this [tutorial](http://blog.alexellis.io/run-iis-asp-net-on-windows-10-with-docker/) to start working with docker on windows.
Everything was fine, but when I build my Dockerfile, image created without a name.
[screen from PowerShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1dz0.png)

How to name this image?

Comment: See that checkmark below the answer below? You can click it to award.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a name or tag of the image.

You can add tag to image.

```
docker tag [imageid] [tag]
```

where [imageid] is the your image ID (85d1607990cd - from your screenshot) and [tag] - is the image tag ("name") for example iis. And as result the full command is:

```
docker tag 85d1607990cd iis
```

You can read more about the image tagging [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/)

Comment: thank you, do you know some good tutorials for someone like who could't understand how docker work and how create a new instance for asp.net mvc application for example

Comment: Docker have not bad docs, this basics [examples](https://docs.docker.com/samples/) can be useful. I don't working with asp.net, can't help in this case.  But the [manual](http://blog.alexellis.io/run-iis-asp-net-on-windows-10-with-docker/) looks quite reasonably. Maybe you just skip some step.

Comment: There's a tutorial here: https://github.com/docker/labs/blob/master/windows/windows-containers/MultiContainerApp.md